# preg_replace - how to match anything that's NOT \*\*

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I can't seem to figure out the regular expression to match any string that's in the format

```
**(anything that's not **)**
```

I tried doing this in php

```
$str = "** hello world * hello **";
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*(([^\*][^\*]+))\*\*/s','<strong>$1</strong>',$str);
```

but no string replacement was done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `?!` paired with a character-wise `.` placeholder:

```
= preg_replace('/\*\*(((?!\*\*).)+)\*\*/s',
```

This basically means to match any number of anythings `(.)+`, but the `.` can never occupy the place of a `\*\*`

Answer (score 1):

You could use lazy match

```
\*\*(.+?)\*\*
# "find the shortest string between ** and **
```

or a greedy one

```
\*\*((?:[^*]|\*[^*])+)\*\*
# "find the string between ** and **,
#  comprising of only non-*, or a * followed by a non-*"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\*\*      # Match **
    (           # Match and capture...
     (?:        # the following...
      (?!\*\*)  # (unless there is a ** right ahead)
     .          # any character
     )*         # zero or more times
    )           # End of capturing group
    \*\*        # Match **
    /sx', 
    '<strong>\1</strong>', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace( '/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $str );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$str = "** hello world * hello **";
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*(.*)\*\*/s','<strong>$1</strong>',$str);
```

Comment: `.*` will also happily match `**`.

Comment: yes, but not the last of them - i think this is what he needs

Comment: Consider `**This is important** this isn't important **but this is**` - your regex will match the entire string instead of only the "important" bits.

Comment: that is true, but in his first example, I think that also the closing ) should be bolded